# fprintf printing a bunch of NULLs at the beginning

Tags: c, file, io

```c
typedef struct record
{
    float field1;
    char *name;
} record;

void printRecordsTo(record **s, char *fileName, int size)
{
    initializePrinter(fileName);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < size)
    {
        printRecordToFile(s[i]);
        i++;
    }
    closePrinter();
}

static int delete = 0; // TODO: Remove
void printRecordToFile(record *r)
{
    if (!file)
    {
        puts("Printer not initialized");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("%d %s", delete ++, toString(r)); // prints all correctly to stdout
    fprintf(file, "%s", toString(r));        // includes many NULLs
}

char *toString(record *s)
{
    float field1 = s->field1;
    int len = 4;
    char *field1Str = malloc(len + 1);
    snprintf(field1Str, len + 1, "%f", field1);
    char *name = s->name;
    char *buf = malloc((1024) * sizeof(char));
    snprintf(buf, 1023, "%s%s%s%s%s\n", "(", name, ", ", field1Str, ")");
    return buf;
}
```

I can't figure out why many NULLs are being printed by the fprintf for large files (of size ~1000 records). The function works fine for the small files (of size ~20 records) I used. I tested it against normal printf which prints the string representations of records correctly.

Comment: The complication and design of this is, among other things, a recipe for leaking memory.

Comment: A `float` may occupy 4 bytes of binary storage, but you'll need more than that to meaningfully `sprintf` one into a string, especially as the default format is 6 decimal places.

Comment: FYI: Your `toString` function leaks at minimum 1KB every call.

Comment: I think that's the cause because it prints ~200 records for 1000 record file. How can I avoid that?

Comment: Man, `toString()` is a redundant call; does no meaningful work.

Comment: @SparKot Returns a string representation of the record?

Comment: @GoldCredential I wouldn't be to sure that the memory leak is the cause of your issues. Leaking 1KB 1000 times is only 1MB, which unless you are running your program on a Tamagotchi, would not be too big of an issue.

Comment: We need a proper [mcve] otherwise we're just lobbing guesses for a solution to a partially-unknown problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Drop `toString()` function from source, it's redundant.
2. Use below statements instead in `printRecordToFile()`

```c
    printf ("%d (%s, %f)", delete++, r->name, r->field1);
    fprintf (file, "(%s, %f)", r->name, r->field1);
```

3. Use meaningful names for structure attributes/members.
4. If you're still seeing garbage values, then perhaps you need to sit with a debugger to find out where structure data is being corrupted. With the info at hand we can only guess.
5. Use [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/downloads/) to trace memory error & leaks. It's a pretty nifty tool for C programmers.

Comment: I made this change and now everything in output file is NULL

Comment: Then, it's very likely that `r->name` is corrupted.

Comment: Ok the code for that: strdup(strtok(line, ","));

Comment: @GoldCredential Provide a proper [mcve] in your question please.

Comment: @SparKot could strdup be causing the error?

Comment: They are all null terminated too. I checked using:  printf("%d\n", r->name[strlen(r->name)]);

Comment: On it's own, no. It has be somewhere else. But it'll worsen the bad condition. Use Valgrind, it'll point out all memory handling mistakes.

Comment: This is what I get: 
```leaks Report Version: 4.0
Process 22451: 211 nodes malloced for 16 KB
Process 22451: 0 leaks for 0 total leaked bytes.```

Comment: I am on MacOS Big Sur, so I don't have access to Valgrind, the above report is the best I could get.

Comment: I've never used MacOS sorry.